# Echo cancellation

Tags: c++, c, encoding, ffmpeg, h.264

Can any of you suggest a good and stable echo cancelation package (gnu or not) to be linked with my videoconference application (C/C++) (Windows / Linux / MacOSX) ? My application should be freeware, so i do not want to pay for each user who download the app.

Answer (score 4):

Oslec is the best I know of.  Might also look into the speex codec stack which includes an echo canceller.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try Oslec. I don't recommend speex for echo cancellation though. We have tried it for a long time with no good results.

Comment: I'm a bit late with the comment, but just in case anyone will read this topic: OSLEC - is a LINE ECHO CANCELLER while SPEEX is an acoustic one. These are completely different things. As you are talking about VOIP application I guess you need AEC (acoustic echo canceller). OSLEC will do nothing with it.

Answer (score 4):

I've used Speex AEC successfully in 2 different VoIP applications.
You might be interested in the [Speex dev group](http://lists.xiph.org/mailman/listinfo/speex-dev) if issues arise.